# VS2015 theme color for #region

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I'm using vs2015, and I like to set #region xyz.... to a black bold font.

By changing  `"PreProcessor Text"`, and `"Preprocessor Keyword"`.
I was able to give them that clear bold look.
However when i hide code by collapsing a #region that bold colour is lost.
I only want the #region to be black bold, and not all other collapsed function/methods. Is that possible in VS2015 ?

Comment: Could you _edit_ your question to include a screenshot that illustrates the issue?

Comment: It sounds like he is saying that he was able to change the color/font of the #region line when the region is expanded, but not when the region is collapsed.  I am able to reproduce this scenario, though I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 13):

After looking at this and other posts on the Internet, this is what worked in VS 2015 for me:

#region and #endregion keywords: **Preprocessor Keyword** [immediately applied]

Text after the #region keyword: **Preprocessor Text** [immediately applied]

Collapsed region: **Collapsed Text (Collapsed)** [must restart Visual Studio]

[A Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64HT4.png)

Comment: Emphasis on the Visual Studio restart for Collapsed Text because this subtle point cost me a lot of time until you pointed it out.

Answer (score 3):

In the Visual Studio Fonts and Colors dialog, find items named "Collaps...". You can play with colors there.

You can make a collapsed region font bold by changing message box font in the system display properties to be bold.
But don't tell anyone about this because if M$ discovers and patches this loophole you will get stuck with non-bold font for another 10 years. :)

Comment: Thanks! I tried this before but it didn't work. Apparently you need to restart VS for this particular item.